# I'm trying to add a reminder function which reminds with a messagebox and time.sleep() unfortunately freezes the entire program

Tags: python, tkinter, time

time.sleep() works but it freezes the entire program, I've tried other options like Timer, Freecadgui and others but still failing. Please assist if possible

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import customtkinter
import time

window = customtkinter.CTk()

def top_level():

    # Create a Top Level Window
    top = Toplevel()

    # Create a title and geometry for Top
    # Level Window
    top.title("TopLevel Window")
    top.geometry('600x600')

    # Display a message on Top Level Window
    msg = Message(top, text="Text on TopLevel window", width=150)
    msg.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=12)
    #the Reminder section
    lable_remind = customtkinter.CTkLabel(top, text = 'Remind me about:', font = ('arial', 21))  
    label_time = customtkinter.CTkLabel(top, text = 'In how many minutes?', font = ('arial', 21))              
    lable_remind.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=12)  
    label_time.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=12)
    entry_box = Text(top, height=1, width=20, font=('arial', 21))
    entry_box.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=12)
    entry_time = FloatEntry(top, font=('arial', 21))
    entry_time.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=12)
    def reminder():
        msg = entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c")
        time_rem = entry_time.get()
        local_time = float(time_rem)
        local_time = local_time * 60
        time.sleep(local_time)
        messagebox.showinfo(title=None, message=msg)
        
    button_rem = customtkinter.CTkButton(top, width=120, height=40, border_width=0, corner_radius=20, text="Remind me", command=reminder)
    button_rem.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    # Make a function for exit button
    def exit_btn():
        top.destroy()
        top.update()

    # Create a button to exit Top Level Window
    btn = Button(top, text='EXIT', command=exit_btn)
    btn.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Button(window, text="Create a TopLevel window", command=top_level).grid(row=8, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
window.mainloop()
```

The code above opens a top level window with the reminder function.

Comment: The FloatEntry() class is coded in another part of the code, you have to use another entry widget to try the code.

Comment: Well sleep puts the thread in sleep. What would you expect?

Comment: Instead of `time.sleep` use the `after` method. See e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks but after method also freezes the whole program

Comment: Add the code that uses `.after()` in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all
I've managed to fix the problem (Alhamdulillaah) with a bit of research.
We need to "import threading" then use this to run the function.
See below for example.
This way it(The reminder section) wont freeze the rest of the app...

```
    #the Reminder section
    lable_remind = customtkinter.CTkLabel(top, text = 'Remind me about:', font = ('arial', 21))  
    label_time = customtkinter.CTkLabel(top, text = 'In how many minutes?:', font = ('arial', 21))              
    lable_remind.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=12)  
    label_time.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, pady=12)
    entry_box = Text(top, height=1, width=20, font=('arial', 21))
    entry_box.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=12)
    entry_time = FloatEntry(top, font=('arial', 21))
    entry_time.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=12)
    def reminder():
        msg = entry_box.get(1.0, "end-1c")
        time_rem = entry_time.get()
        local_time = float(time_rem)
        local_time = local_time * 60
        t.sleep(local_time)
        messagebox.showinfo(title=None, message=msg)
        top.destroy()
        top.update()
        
    def another_thread():
        # Start the download in a new thread.
        r = threading.Thread(target=reminder)
        r.start()
    button_rem = customtkinter.CTkButton(top, width=120, height=40, border_width=0, corner_radius=20, text="Remind me", command=another_thread)
    button_rem.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def new_thread():
    # Start the download in a new thread.
    t = threading.Thread(target=top_level)
    t.start()
        
#Button(window, text="Set a reminder", command=new_thread).grid(row=8, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
button_remind = HoverButton(window, text="Set a reminder", activebackground='yellow', command=new_thread).grid(row=8, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
```

I hope this makes sense to all.
All the best